Replacement for missing downshift (low) gear lever
I have a MTB with 2x8 Shimano Altus EZ fireplus.
On the right handlebar with the 8 speed, the gear lever to downshift gear got loose and fell off.
So basically can't downshift gears. Id hate to spend 40ish quid to buy replacements when all I need is the plastic lever.
Any ideas please?

Maybe you could add a photo to your question, so we can see what it looks like

I'm not sure if it's just a shift lever or a combo shift-brake lever you require, but here's a photo of the shift-brake combo. I live in the U.S. so am not familiar with the quid, but the price here is reasonable and if you value your time any, this would be economical compared to searching for a replacement lever, paying for the cost of that and then faffing around trying to put it in your current shifter.  If there are bicycle co-ops (place where people donate used parts and bikes and volunteers help with maintenance issues) in your area, you could look in their bins to find a replacement shifter or one you could cannibalize for parts.  Again, this would be time consuming vs. getting a new one shipped to you.



The US dollar, UK pound and the euro (most of the rest of Europe) are in the same range, about 1 to 1.20 or less at most times.

So, a "quid" is another term for a pound?
